# Keeping Azure DNS Name when changing to new (Resource Manager) servers

Tags: azure, dns

So I have been running Azure VM's in the classic portal for a while now but I need to increase the performance on them and I am thinking of moving to the Premium VM's. The problem that I found during testing is that the DNS names have changed. So they aren't 'servicename.cloudapp.net' anymore, they are like, 'servicename.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com'. I need to keep the DNS name the same with 'servicename.cloudapp.net'.
I have tried redirecting it through our third party DNS service but it isn't possible.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DNS format for v2 (Resource Manager VMs) is <hostname>.<regionname>.cloudapp.azure.com There is no way to change this.

If you need to keep servicename.cloudapp.net, the only way you can do so is to remain on v1 virtual machines.

**edited to address comment**

I would imagine that at some point in future v1 VMs will be retired and you will need to figure out how to migrate these users away from the current configuration.

It would  be prudent to begin that process now while there is no time pressure.

I would imagine the best way forward would to initially configure a DNS CNAME record to point to the existing database and start migrating users over to that. Once you have transferred everyone you can then switch over to v2 VMs and they'll never notice.

Customers are quite comfortable with the concept of updates, so as long as you make the process as painless as possible for them (i.e. just a single executable etc) then it is unlikely they'll mind. Especially if you can roll out some sort of free upgrade along with it.

Comment: Ah damn it... I need to keep it the same because many customers are using this name to connect to a database.

Comment: @T-BONE I have amended my answer

Comment: Thank you for the update. That is a good idea and I will be considering it, I will need to wait a while though as we have already had downtime moving the servers to the Azure platform. Now they have released the Premium Storage (V2) we need to move them again as the servers are running slower than expected.

Comment: If you can give them a boost in performance, that can certainly be the upgrade to sell them on. 'We need to apply this upgrade to rollout new servers to give better performance' that's always an easy sell!

Comment: Haha that is true, but that's what we used when doing the initial move to Azure. But we will work something out... Thank you again for your help

Comment: when putting a cname in front of the database you could consider Azure Traffic Manager, it will allow you to do failover, load balancing, geo-aware routing etc. should you ever need them.  Also, it's hosted by MSFT along with the DB.